# Where().Count() vs. Count()

Tags: vb.net, performance, linq, list

Here's an excerpt of the relevant portion of my class that inherits from `List(Of T)`. Take a look at `SelectedObjects` and `SelectedCount` properties. I added `SelectedCount` for performance reason, but am now wondering if it is any better than `SelectedObjects.Count()`.

```
Public Class DrawingObjectsList
    Inherits List(Of DrawingObjectBase)

  Friend ReadOnly Property DOsOfCurrentFace As IEnumerable(Of DrawingObjectBase)
    Get
        Return Me.Where(Function(DObj) DObj.Face = mFace)
    End Get
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property SelectedObjects() As IEnumerable(Of DrawingObjectBase)
    Get
        Return DOsOfCurrentFace.Where(Function(DObj) DObj.IsSelected = True)
    End Get
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property SelectedCount() As Integer
    Get
        Return DOsOfCurrentFace.Count(Function(DObj) DObj.IsSelected = True)
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

My theory is that both `Where(predicate).Count()` and `Count(predicate)` will need to iterate the List and thus there shouldn't be any considerable difference. Also since I didn't do any `ToList()` or `ToArray()` on `Where()`, I'm unsure if calling `Count()` on it will be able to take advantage of built-in `Count` property or not.

So should I keep or remove `SelectedCount` property?

Comment: If you're *wondering* whether doing something for performance reasons is worth it, there's an obvious way to find out: measure it.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Correct, but I also want to get my theory evaluated by pros.

Comment: Well why don't you do the measurement *now*, and add it to the question... as well as trying to work out whether the time taken by `Count` is actually significant in your app at all.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet said in the comments the best way to find out is to measure.
However, if you are *also* using `SelectedObjects`, I would remove `CountObjects`. The reason is the following:

- If your `IEnumerable` is an in-memory list, then as you mention `CountObjects` will go through the original list again. If you already have called `SelectedObjects` and have the result in a variable, calling `Count` will just call a property on the list and give you the number of objects right away without looping through it again. If you haven't called `SelectedObjects` then I think that calling `.Where(...).Count()` is not *slower* than `.Count(...)`. This is something you should test though.
- If you `IEnumerable` is an `IQueryable` then either it has been materialized, in which case it doesn't matter, or - if it hasn't been materialized - then I expect a call to `.Where(...).Count()` will translate into the same `SELECT COUNT(*)` query that `.Count(...)` will. Again, this is something you should test.

Comment: in the case of `IQueryable` it is important to realize that the `.Where` method and `.Count` methods is VERY different in those. Relying on inheritance/polymorphism will cause .net to load your table, then count Objects.

Answer (score 0):

I timed it with some (rather naive) code:

```
Dim r = New Random()
Dim sw As Stopwatch
Dim list = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000000).Select(Function(x) r.Next)

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
list.Count(Function(x) x Mod 2 = 0)
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
Dim x = list.Where(Function(x) x Mod 2 = 0).Count()
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
```

The results I got were

```
Count   Where/Count
-------------------
3494    3624
3484    3612
3523    3617
3522    3609
3500    3623
3493    3631
3536    3620
3541    3682
3621    3633
3515    3686
```

On average, using `Where/Count` took about 4% longer (in this case an average of 110 ms more). So there *might* be a performance benefit to doing just `Count`. However, you'd want to confirm that holds true in your specific scenario/environment first. Take a look at Eric Lippert's [C# Performance Benchmark Mistakes](http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one) for good tips on how to do that.